# Iterate through KML using getPlacemarks

Tags: java, android, kml, marker

so I have a KML layer which I create like so:

```
inputStream = new URL("url here").openStream();
layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, getApplicationContext());
```

The layer no contains many different placemarks which I can retrieve by using `layer.getPlacemarks()`. MY issue is that I want a why to somehow iterate through the placemarks, check if they are a certain distance from my current location and if they are then display that marker on the map. I'm fine finding the distance, I just don't understand how to access the placemarks and use specific information from it to calculate the distance etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (KmlPlacemark placemark: layer.getPlacemarks()) {

   if (placemark instanceof KmlPoint) {
     KmlPoint point = (KmlPoint) placemark;
     LatLng latLng = point.getGeometryObject();

     // https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/kml

   }       
}
```

Placemarks can be other types too. Check the source on github on how to get the coords from the other types.

Comment: How do I get the coordinated from geometry? I see how its extracted but I can't seem to find how to get those coordinates now